# How to simplify a class with lot's of copy-pasted error handling code?

Tags: java, exception

In some old Java code, I found a class that contains a lot of methods that all use the same error handling code (try-catch with a lot of error handling, logging and so on). It looks like the first method was simply copied and then the code in the try block was slightly adapted. Here is what it basically looks like:

```
public class myClass{

    public void doSomething() {
        try {
           //do something
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //extensive error handling
        }
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        try {
           //do something else
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //extensive error handling, copy-pasted from the above method
        }
    }
```

}

How could this be simplified? I don't want to change the interface of the class (much), I'd just like to get rid of the copy-pasted catch blocks, so that only the code from the try block stays within the original method.

I thought about using the Factory Method pattern, where one method implements the error handling and calls the original method in the try block. But then, all calls would have to go through this method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just put the common code in a method that you call from both catch blocks?

Comment: why don't you simply write a static method in an exception handler class, to be called in the catch block? then catch block will only have a couple of instructions (call to the exception handler, return).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplify it the same way you simplify all other repeated code: Put the repeated code in a method, and call the method:

```
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        //do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError(e);
    }
}

public void doSomethingElse() {
    try {
        //do something else
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleError(e);
    }
}

private void handleError(Exception e) {
    //extensive error handling
}
```

Comment: But then don't you have to do instanceof specificException, instanceof otherSpecificException and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You could just extract the copy-pasted code in a private method taking an `Exception` an an argument.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, probably the best you will get is simply to pull out the contents of the `catch` block into a new method. Each method will still have to repeat:

```
try {

}
catch(Exception e) { handleError(e); }
```

If you want to get more concise than that, you will have to start doing some exotic things (like using macros and running a preprocessor over the code).

If you were using a higher-level language like Clojure or Ruby, you would have more options, but Java is rather limited in this regard.